# iPhone 4s looking simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

How do I get an iPhone simulator that has the shape of the iPhone 4 or 4s device?

The latest SDKs have an iPhone simulator with retina display however the simulator is vertically larger than my mac pro resolution and is just a simple window with no iPhone 4 or 4s device shape around the simulator.am I doing anything wrong?

Basically, I would like to record the simulation for a trailer of a game I am making. I saw some iPhone trailers on YouTube where the have a simulator that have the new iPhone 4 or 4s handset design rather than the old iPhone 3G/s design. How do i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have removed your reference to resources still covered by your NDA. Be mindful please.

Comment: If you're in the latest SDK, your standard iPhone simulator should have the design of the 4/4s...at least mine does

Comment: Is the simulator covering the whole screen? Mine seems to be larger vertically than the entire screen. Maybe that's why?

Comment: If the simulator is larger than your screen resolution, yes, you loose the bezel.  But I am talking about the standard iPhone (non-retina) simulator.

Comment: The none retina simulator still shows the old phone design (3G/S)

Comment: Even though I have the latest Xcode and have downloaded all versions of the simulator.

Comment: my mistake, the none retina simulator does actually show the new iPhone design. However, the colours are not correct, it seems to be using lower bits colour system rather than full 32-bit colour. Any ideas why this could be happening. On the actual device, the colours are full 32-bit colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the extremely high pixel density of a retina display, creating a video with pixel-perfect retina graphics will require you to have a really big monitor.  The is because monitors have far less pixel density than an retina display.  The best way to accomplish your video is to use the non-retina simulator.

If you really need to have the full retina resolution and have a large enough monitor to display it, you can get retina graphics with the nice 4s overlay by using a third part app call Reflection.  You can check it out here: http://www.reflectionapp.com/

Comment: I am assuming that reflectionapp will not be able to produce the same frame rate as the iPhone on the mac. Is that correct?

Comment: Does it look choppy or is the video smooth?

Comment: I don't care about the exact frameless rate. Just wondering if the video will be smooth if I use reflection app to record trailer. The reason I ask is because I would like to make a trailer of a game. So I am wondering to buy it or not.

Comment: I think it looks great.  I use it for online-presentations and meetings all the time. I've made videos with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Open the simulator.

At the top select "Hardware/Device/iPhone".  DO NOT select "Hardware/Device/iPhone (Retina)".

The end.

Comment: And you think I did not know that?

Comment: You asked the question "How do I get an iPhone simulator that has the shape of the iPhone 4 or 4s device?" and I answered you.  If you already knew that then why would you ask it?